# Select best Azure storage for visualization and analysis

Tags: azure, bigdata, azure-eventhub

I am writing tool to analyze data coming from a race simulator, I have two use cases:

1. Display live telemetry on a chart - so mostly visualization of incoming stuff, to detect manually anomalies
2. Calculate own metrics, analyze data and suggest actions based on them - this can be done after a session, doesn't have to be calculated live. Now I am focusing solely on storing data but I have to keep in mind that later it needs to be analyzed.

I was thinking about utilizing Event Hub to handle streaming of events, question is how to visualize data in the easiest way and what's the optimal storage for second use case - it has to be big data solution I believe, there will be many datapoints to analyze.

Answer (score 0):

For visualization you can use Power Bi or another visualization tool running on containers.

For storing, you can go with Azure Time Series Insights or just sink from Event Hubs to Azure Cosmos DB and then, connect power bi on it to create your charts.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/overview-what-is-tsi